# Update a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to update the data on the database once I get all the values of that data with current DateTime..i.e

My Model:

```
class Load_Balancing(models.Model):

    instance_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instance_visit = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the value with the last sequence number inserted in the database and update its time to the `current` time.

I tried:

```
instances = Load_Balancing.objects.all().order_by("-sequence")[:1]
a = Load_Balancing.objects.filter(sequence=instances.sequence).update(instance_visit= datetime.datetime.now())
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I am getting an error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sequence' "

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the latest one, you can do that with:

```
from django.utils import timezone

instance = Load_Balancing.objects.all().latest('sequence')
instance.instance_visit = timezone.now()
instance.save()
```